# how do you add charts to dashboard in Kibana 4?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I am trying to create dashboard with multiple different charts in them. I am confused. Do I have to create each charts, save them and then add them to the dashboard or within the dashboard, I can create different charts and add it to the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to create each charts, save them and then add them to the
>   dashboard

Yes. To a visualization to dashboard you first need to creat it from `Visualize` tab and save it with a name. Afterwards you can add already created visualizations by clicking that button:

[image]

The empty page says it all:

[image]